# Python - Tkinter and thread lock problems

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, locking

I've got three threads.

- One for getting Data from a device.
- One for calculation something
- and the last is a tkinter thread

I'm using a Thread lock with

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

I have two functions which need the lock:

```
def reset_to_0():
    
    global lock
    #with lock:
    print("resetting to zero")
    print(lock.locked())
    
    while lock.locked():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("reset for lock")
    lock.acquire()
    print(lock.locked())
    try:
        #communication with the device via usb
        ...
        lock.release()
        
    except Exception as e:
        lock.release()
        log.error("Error: " + str(e))
```

and

```
def updater():
   global lock
   print("in Updater")
   print(lock.locked())
   while lock.locked():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(" upda for lock")
   lock.acquire()
   print(lock.locked())
   print("getting data") # connection with the device
   roh_daten = matic.alle_daten() # This gets some data from a device (array)
   print(len(roh_daten))
   ...
   print("done updating")
   lock.release()
```

(Please ignore the wrong indentations I had to shorten the functions)
the **updater** function is started form a Thread at the beginning of the code
the **reset_to_0** function is called from multiple other functions for example via an button on the GUI of Tkinter.

```
upda = threading.Thread(target=updater)
upda.start()
```

As you can see the functions each wait for the lock to be released ( I tried it without this "waiting" to no result). I also tried using  `with lock:` insted of `lock.acquire() and lock.release()` to no result.

The funcions are using lock globaly. At the beginning I was giving the functions the lock but I can't do this anymore due to the reset function being called from a tkinter window without the lock.

Sometimes my code just freezes and one function is waiting for the lock to be released without the other tread working.

Here is an output example:

```
in Updater
False
True
getting Data
24
done updating
in Updater
False
True
getting Data
resetting to zero
True
24
reset for lock
reset for lock
reset for lock
...
```

I think the tkinter button was pressed while the Updater was doing its thing and had the lock.
then the reset_to_0 function was called, it executed some lines and after printing the state of the lock and waiting for it to be released the Updater came in and did some lines again after which the while loop in the reset_to_0 took over. But the code never goes back to the Updater to finish what it started and the code is frozen.
Has anyone an idea on how to prevent this?

The only option I see is letting the Updater reset the device as well which it checks for over an global variable (I dislike this version because I can't make sure the reset is happening asap)
(Sorry if something is missing I needed to copy the code and shrink it down. I also couldn't copy paste the output due to the code running on a different machine)

Comment: Note that using `with lock: ...` will wait for the lock and you don't need to check whether the lock is released or not.

Comment: @acw1668 Yeah I know but Ive tried both with no result